# MultiDexTestRunner does not work with MultiDexApplication

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-instrumentation

I'm using:

- Android Studio 1.1.0
- Gradle 2.2.1
- Android Plugin for Gradle: 1.1.0

We have recently moved to Android Studio and we are trying to make our instrument test work. However when I run the test, it gives me error

Running tests
Test running startedTest running failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{com.xxx.xxx.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}
Empty test suite.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Please see config below:

**Application class:**

```
public class XxxApp extends MultiDexApplication
{
...
}
```

**App build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.7'
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:2.0'
    compile project(':Common')
    compile project(':zxing-lib')
    androidTestCompile fileTree(dir: 'test-libs', include: '*.jar')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support:multidex-instrumentation:1.0.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.+'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.+'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"
    enforceUniquePackageName false
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxx"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testApplicationId "com.xxx.xxx.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner'
        // Does not work testInstrumentationRunner 'com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        androidTest.setRoot('tests')
        androidTest.java.srcDir('tests/src')
        androidTest.res.srcDir('tests/res')
        androidTest.assets.srcDirs('tests/assets')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

**Test class**

```
public class XxxTests extends InstrumentationTestCase
{
   public void testXxx()
   {
    ...
   }
}
```

**Top level build.gradle**

```
dependencies 
{
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0+'
}
```

Comment: Several questions for you: Have you hit the dex limit? Why use MultiDex? Post an example test, the test you posted is empty which is why you are getting your error.

Comment: We are using a third party component which requires us to make our app multidex. Just consider assertTrue(true); as statement in test to make it real simple!

Comment: Post your entire `build.gradle`. Yes, but the test is empty and there for you get the error you posted.

Comment: Post everything in your `build.gradle.`

Comment: UPDATE: I have added complete build.gradle. Plus the test seems to work when I just use plan InstrumentationRunner instead of multi dex runner.

Comment: few more questions: 1) You do not need multidex, have you tried not using it? 2) Are your tests in `androidTest`?

Comment: 1) Unfortunately we have to due to third party component : https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/articles/gettingstarted/index.html
2) We are using custom directory structure configured through gradle

Comment: What are you testing? Why do you need to extend `InstrumentationTestCase` rather than a more specialized test case such as `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`?

Answer (score 1):

The exact situation described in the original question may be related to older versions of the tools.

I'm adding my experience here, because this is one of the first Google hits when searching with the `... Unable to find ... ComponentInfo ...` error message.

With recent versions of tools and android plugin it seems you don't need anything else than following in `build.gradle` to get tests to work with `multiDexEnabled true`:

```
...
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner"
    }
}
```

(I have `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0`)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what `compile project(':Common')` is, most likely an Android Library; however, besides that library there is no reason for you to use `MultiDex`.

In order to use `InstrumentationTestRunner` you need Instrumentation Tests in the `androidTest` folder.

I would highly suggest you move your "Eclipse-based" project structure to Android Studio's default Gradle structure: "`src/main/java`, `src/test/java` and `src/androidTest/java`"

**Top `build.gradle`:**

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3' // <-- Updated
}
```

**App `build.gradle`:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile project(':Common') // <-- Not sure what this is
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.7'
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:2.0' // <-- There is a newer versoin, but might break your current code
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.+'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.+'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"
    enforceUniquePackageName false

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxx"
        testApplicationId "com.xxx.xxx.test"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        androidTest.setRoot('tests')
        androidTest.java.srcDir('tests/src')
        androidTest.res.srcDir('tests/res')
        androidTest.assets.srcDirs('tests/assets')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

Comment: As per documentation, we can configure our own structure in gradle. I don't see any reason to do it immediately. See project structure at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

Comment: @Adil Try out my `build.gradle` that I posted. Obviously you can change your source sets. I was just making a suggestion for the long term.

Comment: As I mentioned in comments, it works with simple InstrumentationTestRunner but doesn't run with multidex which was suggested in documentation https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: You do not need Multidex then? Why are you trying to use it?

Comment: I wonder the documentation asked to use multi dex instrumentation runner for multi dex application!!

Comment: @Adil You application does not NEED multidex. Please read my comments and test my answer out. The bounty ends in 2 days.

Comment: Your answer does not have anything new. I already tried out InstrumentationTestRunner as mentioned in question and comments earlier. My confusion was that as my app is extending MultiDexApplication then why I was unable to run MultiDexTestRunner as described in google documentation.

Comment: My answer is to help get you moving into the correct direction as I have tried to explain many times: you do not need multidex. I have updated your  question. It took since March 16th to clarify that you want to use the MultiDexRunner for no reason.

Comment: I apologize I may not be clear enough but as stated on my comment on 19th March. We are using Adobe creative SDK which requires us to use MultiDexApplication. See https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/articles/gettingstarted/index.html and https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/articles/imageediting/index.html

Are you suggesting that despite using multidex app we still dont need multi dex test runner?

Comment: @Adil I never saw that comment. Now I see that you are *forced* to use the MultidexRunner. I am not sure why you can't. Remember, the "runners" are only for view tests. You should be able to unit test your app without it. I see "`Note: We strongly recommend to extends the MultiDexApplication from the multidex support library.`". Have you tried **not** using MultiDex?

Comment: Not really. As mentioned in my question, it works with android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner but does not work com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner

Comment: As I have asked many times, have you tried compiling you app without it. Do you actually need to use multidex? Are you libraries and codebase actually that large?

Comment: Yes multidex is required